# How to avoid that tested page exits iframe in Cypress after login on test page

Tags: cypress

I'm new to Cypress. Our test application requires a login of the user. After login he/she is redirected to the application page itself (a React application).

**Desired behaviour:** I wish that the test application remains in the Cypress-iframe.

**Actual behaviour:** After login the application takes the full screen of the Cypress window. (It does not show the current test outcome on the left side any more. Instead the application is now full screen within Cypress)

**Question:**
How can I avoid that the application under test takes full size and exits its iframe on the right?

[image]

Comment: I just found out that the reason was that I was calling an https - page as http and then was transferred to https.
After calling https://.... the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is your app is doing a JavaScript redirect via setting `window.top.location`, which breaks out of the iframe Cypress placed it in.

You need to either disable this code, or make sure it doesn't run (by ensuring the JavaScript redirect is not ran)